# With set-user-ID bit on, are both the process's EUID and saved set-user-ID changed to the file's user ID?

Tags: files, process, uid

From APUE

> The saved set-user-ID is copied from the effective user ID by `exec` functions. If the ﬁle’s set-user-ID bit is set, this copy is saved **after** `exec` stores the effective user ID  from the ﬁle’s user ID.

Does it mean that

- first the process's EUID is changed to the file's user ID,
- then the  process's saved set-user-ID is changed to the  process's EUID?

So both the process's EUID and saved set-user-ID are changed to the file's user ID?

Comment: From the text, I would say the saved set-user-ID is set to the true uid of the user that invoked the binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation in `credentials(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) clarifies this a bit for Linux systems:

> **User and group identifiers**
>
> Each process has various associated user and group IDs.  These IDs
>   are integers, respectively represented using the types `uid_t` and
>   `gid_t` (defined in `<sys/types.h>`).
>
> On Linux, each process has the following user and group identifiers:
>
> - Real user ID and real group ID.  These IDs determine who owns the
>     process.  A process can obtain its real user (group) ID using
>     `getuid(2)`.
> - Effective user ID and effective group ID.  These IDs are used by
>     the kernel to determine the permissions that the process will have
>     when accessing shared resources such as message queues, shared
>     memory, and semaphores.  On most UNIX systems, these IDs also
>     determine the permissions when accessing files.  However, Linux
>     uses the filesystem IDs described below for this task.  A process
>     can obtain its effective user (group) ID using `geteuid(2)`.
> - Saved set-user-ID and saved set-group-ID.  These IDs are used in
>     set-user-ID and set-group-ID programs to save a copy of the
>     corresponding effective IDs that were set when the program was
>     executed (see `execve(2)`).  A set-user-ID program can assume and
>     drop privileges by switching its effective user ID back and forth
>     between the values in its real user ID and saved set-user-ID.
>     This switching is done via calls to `seteuid(2)`, `setreuid(2)`, or
>     `setresuid(2)`. A set-group-ID program performs the analogous tasks
>     using `setegid(2)`, `setregid(2)`, or `setresgid(2)`. A process can
>     obtain its saved set-user-ID (set-group-ID) using `getresuid(2)`.
>
> [...]

I made a test program to take a look at what happens:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getuids(uid_t *uids) {
  if(getresuid(&uids[0], &uids[1], &uids[2]) == -1) {
    perror("Unable to get UIDs\n");
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int getgids(gid_t *gids) {
  if(getresgid(&gids[0], &gids[1], &gids[2]) == -1) {
    perror("Unable to get GIDs\n");
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  uid_t uids[3];
  gid_t gids[3];

  if(getuids(uids) && getgids(gids)) {
    printf("Real ID: user %d, group %d\n", (int)uids[0], (int)gids[0]);
    printf("Effective ID: user %d, group %d\n", (int)uids[1], (int)gids[1]);
    printf("Set-ID: user %d, group %d\n", (int)uids[2], (int)gids[2]);

    seteuid(uids[0]);
    getuids(uids);
    getgids(gids);
    printf("Effective ID: user %d, group %d\n", (int)uids[1], (int)gids[1]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the file:

```
server /home/erik # ls -l perms
-r-sr-sr-x 1 nobody nobody 8280 Apr 26 00:36 perms
```

Running as `root`:

```
server-calgary /home/erik # ./perms
Real ID: user 0, group 0
Effective ID: user 65534, group 65534
Set-ID: user 65534, group 65534
Effective ID: user 0, group 65534
```

Running as `erik`:

```
erik@server ~ $ ./perms
Real ID: user 1000, group 1000
Effective ID: user 65534, group 65534
Set-ID: user 65534, group 65534
Effective ID: user 1000, group 65534
```

As my test program shows, if a file is set-ID, the EUID/EGID starts with whatever the owner/group is on the file (only set-UID and set-UID+GID permissions work!), but it can be changed between that and the caller's real ID if the program wants.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure if I understand your reply. Does it mean that If the executable ﬁle’s set-user-ID bit is set,  `exec` functions will 

    first change the process's EUID to the file's user ID, and

    then change the process's saved set-user-ID to the process's EUID?

So both the process's EUID and saved set-user-ID are changed to the file's user ID?

Comment: @Tim That's probably the startup process works internally (although since the kernel's doing it, both could be set at the same time, and you wouldn't be able to tell the difference!)

Comment: What is the purpose of having both the process's EUID and saved set-user-ID set to the file's user ID? For what purpose will the value in saved set-user-ID be used?

Comment: As the documentation indicates (and my program does), the program can switch between the set-ID and real-ID at any time; they have to be saved so that the program (and the kernel) knows what those IDs are.

Comment: "they have to be saved so that the program (and the kernel) knows what those IDs are", do you mean the file's owner user ID by "they"? The file is always there for query for its owner user ID, so why is its owner user id have to be saved?

Comment: "They" is the set of real and set-ID identifiers. As for why it has to be saved, the kernel needs to know which IDs are valid for the program to switch between (coincidentally, so might the program), so it makes sense to have it stored; additionally, the ownership and permissions information can be changed even if the program is running, so it might not be the same as when the program started!

Comment: @Tim also having a separate explicit saved uid, allows the setuid binaries to drop privileges permanently if needed (suppose before executing some user script). If this bit was always checked from the binary (and suppose the binary had setuid bit and was owned by root), there would be no way to drop these privileges. The user code following this could make the setuid system call and regain root privileges. It just gives more control to the user.